# Getting the admin's SID

Tags: cmd

How do I get only the administrator account's sid using the wmic useraccount command in windows cmd ?

```
wmic useraccount get sid where admin=true
```

should be something like that I guess.

Comment: Sorry for asking i flipped the get and the where places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `administrator`'s SID by doing this:

```
wmic useraccount where name='administrator' get sid
```

This returns a result similar to this:

```
SID
S-1-5-21-4067126559-1921051348-1512596144-500
```

Comment: yes man thanks i just realized that i flipped their places sorry for making trouble

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to well known SIDs we know that an admin account is always going to start with  S-1-5- and ends with -500 (http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/07/22/how-can-i-determine-if-the-local-administrator-account-has-been-renamed-on-a-computer.aspx). This also ensures you are getting the admin account even if somebody renamed it from administrator

```
wmic useraccount where "SID like 'S-1-5-%-500'" get sid
```

Comment: @GeorgiDzhondzhov sure, now just be sure to mark one (or both) of ours as answers so folks know.